# Error To Many Redirects - ScriptResource.axd

Tags: web, sharepoint, dns

We have a website built on SharePoint 2016. When you go to "https://www.ghcscw.com" it can find the ScriptResource.axd file and everything works fine. When you go to "https://ghcscw.com" its tries to find the ScriptResource.axd file multiple times returning a 302 and then fails. This breaks the SharePoint search functionality (I believe it's the ajax functionality).

Here are the specific errors. If anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated:

/ScriptResource.axd Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS /WebResource.axd Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS (index):230 Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined at (index):230 sp.init.js?rev=LHfxXsgcQykvazINslGeNQ%3D%3DTAG0:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Type is not defined at sp.init.js?rev=LHfxXsgcQykvazINslGeNQ%3D%3DTAG0:2 sp.core.js?rev=mYpp5rntO3MT6rs6SRo%2BtA%3D%3DTAG0:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Type is not defined at sp.core.js?rev=mYpp5rntO3MT6rs6SRo%2BtA%3D%3DTAG0:2 /favicon.ico Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 0):

They rebooted the SharePoint servers last night and the problem resolved itself.